# Check for NULL prior to Loop Iteration?

Tags: java

Suppose I have

```
List<Attachment> attachments = getAttachments();

for (Attachment a: attachments)
{
  //...
}
```

Do I need to check `attachments != null` prior to doing the collection loop?

Comment: Have you tried what happens if getAttachments() returns null?

Comment: Try it see what happens `for(Atachment a : null){}`

Comment: does `getAttachments()` return null ever? Or does it just return an empty list?

Comment: Is it very hard to answer quickly? that's the point of this forum. The method can return NULL.

Comment: @geneb. questions like this shouldn't be on the forum you can answer yourself with a simple test this just clutters things...

Answer (score 1):

An answer to this entirely depends on your implementation of `getAttachments()`. If this call can ever return `null`, you will need to do null checks otherwise your code can throw a `NullPointerException`. If it can return null, it may be better to change the behavior of `getAttachments()` as it is usually considered bad practice for a `collection` to return null. Try to modify it to return a `Collections.emptyList()` instead.

If you do not want to modify its behavior, a null check is simple to add:

```
List<Attachment> attachments = getAttachments();
if( attachments != null ){
    for (Attachment a: attachments)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends on whether or not `getAttachments()` can return `null`. If it returns `null`, your code will throw a `NullPointerException`. So you will need to check for `null` to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should, if you're not sure that `getAttachments()` doesn't return Collections.EMPTY_LIST instead of null. You will get NPE otherwise.